# Multi Window Application with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have done some basic desktop applications using Java Swing. I however want to use my skills to develop a more complex application that involves user authentication.
I want to have an opening window that will contain `JTextField`s to accept the user's username and password. On successful authentication (checking the user details in the database), I want a new window displayed containing some information about the user.
How can I achieve this multi-window effect using Swing? 
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try and what problem do you encounter?

Comment: Seems like you need to create a custom dialog to perform what you want. JDialog should be useful, or may use JInternalFrame within a JDesktopPane. They are also good solutions.

Comment: Use Dialog boxes for username and password with a button at the bottom to submit them.

Comment: I second Marcelo and @Scarecrow's recommendation. Note that a JOptionPane can function well in this capacity. The object parameter can accept a JPanel with your small sign-in GUI including JLabels, JTextFields and JPasswordFields.

Comment: For example, please have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10150308/522444) for how to use JOptionPanes to create complex modal dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote Blue Peter, "Here's one I made earlier".  I've implemented it as a `JPanel` and then embed it within a `JDialog` in the `main` method.  Note that there's a hook to cause the password field to gain focus when the dialog is first displayed.

```
class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
  private final JTextField userNameTxtFld;
  private final JPasswordField passwordFld;

  public LoginPanel() {
      super(new GridBagLayout()); // GridBagLayout: Not everyone's bag.

      this.userNameTxtFld = new JTextField(12);
      this.passwordFld = new JPasswordField(12);

      userNameTxtFld.setText(System.getProperty("user.name"));

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = INSETS;
      gbc.ipadx = 0;
      gbc.ipady = 0;
      gbc.weightx = 0.0;
      gbc.weighty = 0.0;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;

      int row = 0;
      addLabelledComponent("User Name:", userNameTxtFld, this, gbc, 0, row++);
      //noinspection UnusedAssignment
      addLabelledComponent("Password:", passwordFld, this, gbc, 0, row++);
  }

  private boolean gainedFocusBefore;

  void gainedFocus() {
      if (!gainedFocusBefore) {
          gainedFocusBefore = true;
          passwordFld.requestFocusInWindow();
      }
  }

  String getUserName() {
      return userNameTxtFld.getText();
  }

  String getPassword() {
      return new String(passwordFld.getPassword());
  }

  void reset() {
      passwordFld.setText("");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      final LoginPanel pnl = new LoginPanel();
      JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane(pnl, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,   JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      JDialog dlg = op.createDialog("Login");
      dlg.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {
          @Override
          public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
              pnl.gainedFocus();
          }

          @Override
          public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
          }
      });
      dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      dlg.setVisible(true);
      System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `JDialog` that prompts for user details.
2. Show the dialog.
3. Get the credentials from the dialog*.
4. Authenticate.
5. Create a `JFrame` for your application.
6. Show the frame.

*Don't authenticate from the dialog, just keep your UI to doing UI things.