# how do I re-use an action listener multiple times on a JTextField in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

My program is supposed to get information about a person (first and last names, address, phone) so that it can add the person into an address book.

I made a `JLabel` which gives instructions on what to enter right below. Below the `JLabel` is a `JTextField` which has an `ActionListener` listening to what is being entered. My method has about 8 `ActionListener`'s with 8 `actionPerformed` methods. I am running into trouble it is not working. I can't figure out any other way.

Comment: Your question uses both Swing and SWT tags, and this puts your question into an impossible state -- either this is a Swing question or it's an SWT question, but it can't possibly be both. Please remove the inappropriate tag (likely the SWT tag).

Comment: Swing and swt is the same thing. SWT stands for swing widget something.

Comment: `"Swing and swt is the same thing"` -- No, you are very mistaken, in fact I'd say **extremely** mistaken, as they are two completely different GUI libraries. The text of your question shows that yours is a Swing question -- so get rid of the swt tag, please, for your own good as you will confuse folks on this site if you persist with the wrong tag.

Comment: SWT = "Standard Widget Toolkit". Just Google it before making such statements. Seriously.

Comment: Well i installed a swing library on eclipse and swt was checked so its the same. Both for GUI.  I  am typing on a galaxy s4 so i didn't feel like googlinh it.. too much truble

Comment: Then listen to the experts -- I've used them both, and again you are wrong. But you seem to want to ignore this, so I will leave.

Comment: I've deleted it for you.

Comment: thanks. I didnt know how to delete it so i didn't do it. still the same in my opinion. swing. such a stupid name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to create a form, perhaps with GridBagLayout or MigLayout that holds displays JLabel/JTextField pairs, so that the user can enter all the data on a single simple form, much like most software you use.

If you absolutely must use a single JTextField, then you should use a single ActionListener, but change how it responds based on the *state* of the GUI. That is, perhaps use an int counter variable, that you increment each time data is entered, and base what the listener does with the data based on the value held by the counter.

Comment: I would LOVE  to make a pop out form which asks the user to enter in information on different lines. Only problem is i don't know how to do that and i have googled everywhere with no luck. So if you have a goog tutorial i would love to know. That is my first option. But seems more complex to me.

Comment: @Beatle234: well, take a look at my code and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10150308/522444) that shows just such a form at work.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an instance of the listener and reuse it across the class, like:

```
...

OnChangeListener listener = new OnChangeListener() {
    //All the code here
};

...

textField1.addOnChangeListener(listener);
textField2.addOnChangeListener(listener);
textField3.addOnChangeListener(listener);

...
```