# Inserting JPanel into JOptionPane and retrieving data

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, joptionpane, jradiobutton

I would like to ask you how can I insert JPanel into JOptionPane and retrieve all the information from these JTextFields later on. 
For example I have something like this:

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1);
JPanel up = new JPanel();
JPanel down = new JPanel();
jp.add(up);jp.add(down);
JTextField jt1 = new TextField("habababa1"); jt2 = new JTextField("habababa2");
JRadioButton jrb1 = new JRadioButton("JRB1");
up.add(jt1);down.add(jt2); down.add(jrb1);
```

How do I get data from radioButton etc.?  After I click ok.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952442/how-do-you-return-a-value-from-a-java-swing-window-closes-from-a-button/9952457#9952457).

Comment: I need general idea, not the precise code.

Comment: Thanks Hovecraft but unfortunately it's not the way it's need to be done. I need JOptionPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement an event lister.  Here is a snippet from http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoJRadioButtonEventswithaChangeListener.htm:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class JRadioButtonChangeListener {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grouping Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton aRadioButton = new JRadioButton("A");
    JRadioButton bRadioButton = new JRadioButton("B");

    ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changEvent) {
        AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton)changEvent.getSource();
        ButtonModel aModel = aButton.getModel();
        boolean armed = aModel.isArmed();
        boolean pressed = aModel.isPressed();
        boolean selected = aModel.isSelected();
        System.out.println("Changed: " + armed + "/" + pressed + "/" +
          selected);
      }
    };

    panel.add(aRadioButton);
    group.add(aRadioButton);
    panel.add(bRadioButton);
    group.add(bRadioButton);

    aRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
    bRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: sorry. I answered that from my iPhone where formatting features don't exist.  I'll fix it now.